# Typing rest operator object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, spread-syntax

I was trying to remove a property from an Object using the rest operator and could not figure out how to force a type on the new Object.

```
interface Ab {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

interface Bc {
  b: number;
  c: boolean | undefined;
}

const ab: Ab = { a: 'a', b: 1};
const {a, ...bc} = {...ab, c: true};
```

I know that bc now has a type

```
{
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}
```

is there a way to force `bc` to be explicitly of type `Bc`?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this? Both types are compatible with each other since they have the same structure and Typescript uses structural typing

Comment: It's mainly used for developer sanity when the types are much more complex. They are technically the same, but it would be helpful to know what the exact typing is.
In my case some of the types are of `string | undefined`, so having it as just `string` would be hard to maintain for future devs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty fun and tricky question :)
So here is my solution:

```
interface Abc extends Ab, Bc {
  bc: Bc;
}

const ab: Ab = { a: 'a', b: 1};
const { a, ...bc }: Abc = { ...ab, c: true } as Abc;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Ab%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Bc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Abc%20extends%20Ab%2C%20Bc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20ab%3F%3A%20Ab%3B%0D%0A%20%20bc%3F%3A%20Bc%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0Aor%0D%0Ainterface%20Abc%20extends%20Ab%2C%20Bc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20bc%3A%20Bc%3B%0D%0A%7D*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ab%3A%20Ab%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20'a'%2C%20b%3A%201%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20a%2C%20...bc%20%7D%3A%20Abc%20%3D%20%7B%20...ab%2C%20c%3A%20true%20%7D%20as%20Abc%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Yep, but the aim of question is to explicitly set the type for `bc` variable.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but it seems that the type of bc is `{
    ab?: Ab | undefined;
    bc?: Bc | undefined;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}`
Do you know if it's possible to make the type be `Bc`?

Comment: sure, just declare the Abc interface like this one: `interface Abc extends Ab, Bc { bc: Bc; }`

Comment: I tried it out, but it was still returning type `const bc: { bc: Bc; b: number; c: boolean; }` where `bc.bc` would be `undefined`

Comment: could you share you full example in playground or stackblitz project ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to remove some parts of it. This stackblitz should have the core parts. (I originally had it in a playground, but it was too long)
[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yuwpha)

Comment: It looks like what you are looking for is on the TS team plan :) Check this issue on gihub - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727

Comment: it seems like their solution is slightly different from what I was trying to do. I found a way to type it, but it's pretty ugly. Probably not the most efficient, but should at least allow for typing. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1ogddp

I could also just set another variable with a type https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ykevwb

I don't really like either though :/

Comment: yep :/ looks like overengineered. I think in your case it would be better to avoid using spread/rest operator here.

Comment: ok, i've not tired this but was expecting if you added bc:Bc in the Abc interface that you'd find that bc.bc is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It feels like what you're trying to achieve is very particular to the case you're handling at the moment and not something that can be applied in general.

If I were to take your original example and rename some variables and types (without changing any code), I could get this:

```
interface Human {
  intelligenceQuotient: number;
  speed: number;
}

interface Dog {
  speed: number;
  name: boolean | undefined;
}

const david: Human = { intelligenceQuotient: 100, speed: 5};
const {intelligenceQuotient, ...bc} = {...david, name: "David"};
```

Your question then becomes:
If I remove the `intelligenceQuotient` from `david` and give him a `name`, then why doesn't he become a `Dog`?

A simplified version of the code in your question would be:

```
interface Human {
  numberOfLegs: number;
}

interface Dog {
  numberOfLegs: number;
}

interface DogWithName extends Dog {
  petName: string;
}

const dog: DogWithName = { numberOfLegs: 4, petName: "Snowy" };
const { petName, ...rest } = dog;
```

`rest` is neither `Dog` nor `Human`, it is of type `{ numberOfLegs: number; }`.